# Recognizing set width/height of flash cs5 component?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, components, flash-cs5

i have a class, that extends Sprite and i want to build a Flash CS5 component out of it (using the component panel in Flash CS5, so some designers can benefit from it).

The specialty is, i am overriding the setters/getters of width/height and also scaleX/scaleY of my component, because i want to do some special stuff there, but of course i still call super.width, ...   and so on.

So, i set up everything, drag an instance on the stage at author time, resize it to my needs. But at runtime now, i had to find, that neither my overridden width or height setters, nor my overridden scaleX / scaleY setters are ever called.

Still, my component got resized. So i ask myself, what is Flash CS5 doing to change the size of my component, if it is not using width/height or scaleX/scaleY? Everything else works as expected, i have some parameters, which i set to inspectable and i can set them in the panel in the flash IDE, it just works fine. Only my overridden setters are not called.

Comment: It is probably because your calling the super getter and setter methods. Try removing them and instead storing the values you set and get in private properties such as `_width` and `_height`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it gets resized, I think it gets instantiated with this size. I wrote a test app that shows the width and height are already set in the constructor.